# fb social comments

Tags: 7, social-network

I am using fb social module and have enabled comments for all content types.
All works fine cept i cant find a way to see all comments in one place to manage them all. I have to go to each node manually and check for spam etc. which takes huge amount of time.

So question is, how to check all comments on site generated by fb social comments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that those comments are actually not stored directly on your Drupal site (they're not in your database), so you can't currently list them using views or the regular comment administration screen.

You can look here about some additional information on how facebook plug-ins work: http://www.facebook.com/help/social-plugins (Especially that second paragraph "How do social plugins work?")

Essentially it explains that what you're seeing with the facebook comments plugin is an iframe on your website that is pulling data from facebook directly...

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

As of now, you can use the Facebook Comment Moderation tool available here:
[Facebook Comment MOderation tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments), you will need to create a Facebook App by creating a new App from this page at Facebook: [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

Make sure that you add the "App Domains" under Basic Info and Site URL under "Website with Facebook Login" so that you can use the tool effectively.

Once you have configured it, all the comments will be visible at the page for the specific app that you have connected to the site.